# How can i know threads jobs are done?

Tags: java, multithreading

In class B how can i know jobs of threads are finished? In after properties some worker are running. In class B, I need to know if worker are done?

```
public class A implements InitializingBean{
     public void method1(){
        ...
    }    
    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
        System.out.print("test after properties set");      
        // send threads to executorService
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors
                .newFixedThreadPool(4);
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            Worker worker = new Worker();       
            executorService.submit(worker);
        }
    }
}
public class Worker implements Callable<Void>{
    @Override       
    public void call(){
     ...
   }
}
public class B{
   public void methodB(){
      A a = new A();
     a.method1();
     ///Here How can i know the job of the workers are finished?
   }
}
```

Comment: You can put the log or any alert message at the end of the thread....

Comment: You could implement a callback interface that the thread will call a method of, notifying any listeners of work completion. Similar to what `Service` does with JavaFX applications. You can implement this interface in the class you want to listen for the completion, and the thread will call the method when its work is done.

Comment: You can use a listener/callback pattern, whereby the thread task notifies registered listeners when it's finished

Comment: Do you want to know if all of the jobs are done, or when each of the jobs finish?

Comment: afterPropertiesSet really should probably not be used to spin up an executor service.  This seems weird.  Also afterPropertiesSet is only called if you're using Class A in a Spring AppContext.

Comment: If you just want to make sure method1 is not executed before things are ready, have it throw an exception.

Answer (score 4):

Use a listener/callback pattern to have the thread report completion to a listener. This simple example should show the process:

```
public interface ThreadCompleteListener {
    void workComplete();
}

public class NotifyingThread extends Thread {
    private Set<ThreadCompleteListener> listeners;
    // setter method(s) for adding/removing listeners to go here

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // do stuff
        notifyListeners();
    }

    private void notifyListeners() {
        for (ThreadCompleteListener listener : listeners) {
            listener.workComplete(); // notify the listening class
        }
    }
}
```

in your listening class:

```
NotifyingThread t = new NotifyingThread();
t.addListener(new ThreadCompleteListener() {
    void workComplete() {
        // do something
    }
});

t.start();
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use a Future implementation for your thread. It provides a Future#isDone()

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#isDone()

Answer (score 2):

In general, it is usually more useful to be notified via a callback when jobs complete. However, since others have posted answers which follow that model, I'll instead post a solution that simply allows you to poll and ask whether the jobs are finished, in case this is what fits the needs of your application better.

```
public static interface InitializingBean{
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception;
}

public static class A implements InitializingBean{

    private List<Future<Void>> submittedJobs = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<Future<Void>>());  

    public void method1(){
        //do stuff
    }    
    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
                    System.out.print("test after properties set");      
        // send threads to executorService
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors
                .newFixedThreadPool(4);
        synchronized (submittedJobs) {              
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                Worker worker = new Worker();       
                submittedJobs.add(executorService.submit(worker));
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Allows you to poll whether all jobs are finished or not.
     * @return
     */
    public boolean areAllJobsFinished(){
        synchronized (submittedJobs) {              
            for(Future<Void> task : submittedJobs){
                if(!task.isDone()){
                    return false;
                }
            }

            return true;
        }
    }
}
public static class Worker implements Callable<Void>{
    @Override       
    public Void call(){
     //do worker job

     return null; //to satisfy compiler that we're returning something.
   }
}
public static class B{
   public void methodB(){
      A a = new A();
     a.method1();

     if(a.areAllJobsFinished()){
         System.out.println("Congrats, everything is done!");
     } else {
         System.out.println("There's still some work being done :-(");
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: edited because I realized I forgot the key part of the code where you add the jobs to the submitted jobs list :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to wait in that thread that starts the ExecutorService, you can actually use the awaitTermination method.

At the end of you afterPropertiesSet method, you should add:

```
executorService.shutdown();
```

After this you then add:

```
executorService.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS)
```

This causes the thread to wait for all the executorService's tasks to be done and then continues. So place any code you want to execute after the call to awaitTermination.